# Xcode 7.3.1 :Could not attach to pid : “1601”

Tags: xcode7.3

When I try to run at simulator the "Could not attach to pid : “1601” in xcode 7.3"
error is found.This error pop's up only the first time of running. Any help is greatful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just try to reset the simulator before going to run.

Comment: @BraneDullet i think this is come up with xocde pid issues. Probably apple will fix it with newer versions.